# Open ball (R,d1) with d1=d/1+d

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Can someone help me see why the open ball $B(x,r<1)$ is equal to the points contained in the open interval $]x-\frac{r}{1-r},x+\frac{r}{1-r}[$ for the metric space $(\mathbb{R},d_1)$ with $ d_1(x,y)=\frac{|x-y|}{1+|x-y|}$?

Comment: That is high school algebra. Please show your attempt.

Comment: I think you should show the expression d1<r leads to the stated open interval. When I do some algebra from that starting point it gets a whole mess very quicky.

Comment: You should show whateve you have done so far. That is a requirement for asking 'good question' on this site.

Comment: First try to prove it for $x=0$ (less messy) and then prove that $d_1(x+z,y+z)$ does not depend on $z$. Add the results to your question. Things might still not be completely clear, but then your question is at least improved and more acceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all yo must be sure about what's $B(x,r)$ in $(\mathbb{R},d1)$. What does need some $y\in \mathbb{R}$ to be in $B(x,r)$?.

> \begin{align} y\in B(x,r) \iff d_1(x,y)<r \iff \frac{|x-y|}{1+|x-y|}\iff |x-y|<r+r|x-y| \iff |x-y|<\frac{r}{1-r}\iff \frac{-r}{1-r}<x-y<\frac{r}{1-r}\iff \frac{r}{1-r}>y-x>\frac{-r}{1-r}\iff x+\frac{r}{1-r}>y>x-\frac{r}{1-r}\iff y\in(x-\frac{r}{1-r},x+\frac{r}{1-r}) \end{align}

Comment: " |−|</1−⟺−/1−<−</1− "  this step solved all my confusions. Thank you.